# Authenticating Salesforce users via JWT against ASP.net Web Application

Tags: single-sign-on, .net

We are setting up a Salesforce Community and would like our community members to be able to login using the credentials on an ASP.net website for which they have an account and are most likely already logged in to.

Here's the structure:

Main Site (the ID provider):

> http://www.mainsite.com

Community Site (the Salesforce Communities site):

> http://community.salesforce.com

On our main site, we have implemented a JSON Web Token (JWT) controller for another website already and would like to leverage that investment if possible.

Is is possible to authenticate Salesforce Community members via an external ID provider based on ASP.net membership and if so, are there any guides or examples available to demonstrate this setup in .Net via JWT?

Will Salesforce automatically create new Salesforce users (Community members) upon authenticating with the external ID provider if the user account hasn't already been created?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since posting this question, I found [this terrific post](http://abhisheksubbu.com/2014/10/customizing-registrationhandler-apex-codesalesforce-openid-connect-auth-providers/), which describes how to implement a Registration Handler to create and update Salesforce users based on custom business rules after authentication by an OpenID Connect provider.